# np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit doesn't seem to fit data in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting

I'm trying to run a simple linear fit to 373 data points and yet polyfit seems to fail and I'm not sure why.

```
x = np.reshape(air_sst_new[:,90,180],(373))
y = np.reshape(olr_new[:,90,180],(373))

z = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x,y,1)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y, '.')
xx = np.linspace(np.min(x),np.max(x))
yy = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(xx, z)
plt.plot(xx, yy)
```

[Plot showing original data and the fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Ofd.png)

The code written above works when using randomly generated points which is frustrating.

```
example_x = np.random.rand(373,180,360)
example_y = np.random.rand(373,180,360)

x = np.reshape(example_x[:,90,180], (373))
y = np.reshape(example_y[:,90,180], (373))

z = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x,y,1)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y, '.')
xx = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x))
yy = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(xx, z)
plt.plot(xx, yy)
```

[Plot showing randomly generated data and correct fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8qOf.png)

Comment: Can you create a minimal example that reproduces the behavior. This will make it easier for others to help you. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Let me know if my answer was helpful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the order of arguments in your `polyval`. `z` is your array of linear fit coefficients and `xx` is the refined mesh for plotting the fit.

You **have** used:

```
z = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x,y,1)
yy = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(xx, z)
```

You **should** use:

```
z = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
yy = np.polyval(z, xx)
```

For more details, refer to the official docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html).

Comment: This didn't fix the problem, if I switch xx and z like you suggest it throws an error saying x and y must be the same dimension.

Comment: Ok, check my edit. Try using `np.polyval(z, xx)` on your random example together with `z = np.polyfit(x,y,1)`

Comment: Hmm this also doesn't fix the issue and plots exactly the same issue, I'm inclined to believe that maybe the data I have just ins't suitable for using the polyfit function

Comment: @Steve If your data is like in the plot you show, it should work just fine. Are you sure that there are, e.g., no wired `y`-values? What does `z` look like?

Comment: I had 5 months of NaN values in my data out of the 373 months I had, I checked my Y data but forgot to check my x data. Thanks for you help